# verify a user via e-mail in PHP

Tags: php, email, authentication, verification, email-validation

I'm actually creating a web application using PHP and seek help verifying a user.
As with certain websites, when you register, an e-mail is sent to you with a confirmation link. How do I implement that in PHP?
All I know is that I have to use the PHP `mail()` function to send the e-mail.
Please help. Necessary. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just like with [CSRF](http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries) protection you generate an unique token.

```
$token =  md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
```

You store that value in your session for that email and when the user clicks link in email(you pass token via the [query-string](http://ditio.net/2008/06/12/php-query-string/)) you compare the two values.

To make it more secure you could just as with CSRF add a time-limit.

Comment: why the hell would your run that through md5. You just made a unique key not so unique.

Comment: Thanks Alfred. You got me the right piece of solution to proceed further with the task. Cheers! :)

Comment: @Petah what else would you do?

Comment: @Menasheh something like `bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64))`

Answer (score 7):

Patricks answer is correct altough i want to point out that there are other possibilities!

You don't necessarily have to create and store a unique token in your database. This is data overhead that is only needed once.

You could also take advantage of one-way hashing.

For example send the user the code `md5('my-secret-application-token'.$user_email_adress)`.

You can validate that just the same way but dont need to store a secret code.

Comment: If I steal `my-secret-application-token`, then I can login as any user I would like to :P.

Comment: true @Alfred thats the reason why passwords, keychains, tokens and all that stuff have been created! it would be boring if there werent there for you to steal.

Comment: Thanks Joe. That this problem of mine to an end. Thanks for the help. Stay Connected. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a very broad question, so we can only give a broad answer, but the general technique to do so is

1. insert the user's email address into your database but mark it as unverified
2. create a unique registration key and insert it into a different table just for these keys
3. send an email to the user's email address with a link to your site that passes this registration key as an argument (eg http://site.com/confirm.php?key=1234)
4. when that url is visited, mark the email as verified and remove the temporarily created registration key

Comment: Thanks Patrick. That serves a great help. All three of you (Joe, you and Alfred) have in all given the complete solution to my really "broad" question. Cheers. Stay Connected. :)

Comment: How do you know it was that user that visited the url? Or, is a unique url provided to each user?

Comment: @ggkmath because of step 2, "create a unique registration key". If you use sequential numbers, sure its possible for someone to just guess the next one in the sequence, but if you do something like an md5 sum of a random number, nobody is going to be guessing that.